# While installing gluoncv ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, scipy, pip

I am trying to install gluoncv but this is happening everytime.
**Successfully built ConfigSpace autograd scikit-learn
Failed to build scipy. ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly**

```
 Warning: Unused variable ‘t2’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]                                                                                                    
  stat.h:8:31:                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                       
  Warning: Unused variable ‘t3’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
  stat.h:8:35:
  
  Warning: Unused variable ‘t4’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
  stat.h:8:39:
  
  Warning: Unused variable ‘t5’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
  gfortran:f77: scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/UTIL/smout.f
  gfortran:f77: scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/UTIL/zmout.f
  gfortran:f77: scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/UTIL/ivout.f
  gfortran:f77: scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/UTIL/icnteq.f
  gfortran:f77: scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/UTIL/icopy.f
  gfortran:f77: scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/SRC/ssgets.f
  stat.h:8:27:
  
  Warning: Unused variable ‘t2’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
  stat.h:8:31:
  
  Warning: Unused variable ‘t3’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
  stat.h:8:35:
  
  Warning: Unused variable ‘t4’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
  stat.h:8:39:
  
  Warning: Unused variable ‘t5’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
  gfortran:f77: scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/UTIL/cvout.f
  gfortran:f77: scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/UTIL/dmout.f
  gfortran:f77: scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/UTIL/svout.f
  gfortran:f77: scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/UTIL/zvout.f
  gfortran:f77: /tmp/pip-install-o_n11_7k/scipy_7cdb917d5aa44c05baea31bcea7311d5/scipy/_build_utils/src/wrap_g77_abi_f.f
  error: Command "/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops -Iscipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/SRC -I/tmp/pip-build-env-0hr1_z41/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c -c scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/SRC/cnaup2.f -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/SRC/cnaup2.o" failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
Successfully built ConfigSpace autograd scikit-learn
Failed to build scipy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error while installing gluoncv on a MacOs, but the error happened with ConfigSpace: "Could not build wheels for ConfigSpace which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly"

If you are getting the above error and part of the error log says "Unsupported architecture" or you also had many errors like these:

```
unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'
```

I fixed it by upgrading Python to version 3.8.6 (I had the issue in version 3.8.2).

Comment: Actually, my python version is 3.9.2.

Comment: I know sometimes that's not a possibility but have you tried to downgrade? at least just to see if it works and verify it is a gluoncv-python version issue.